# Running `mut.py` Opens Said File Instead of Running MutPy

Tags: python, testing, mutation-testing

I created a project that follows the example in MutPy's [***README file.***](https://github.com/mutpy/mutpy#example)

However, when I run `mut.py --target calculator --unit-test test_calculator -m`, it just opens `mut.py` instead of actually running MutPy.

The file has the following content:

```
#!c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe

import sys
from mutpy import commandline

if __name__ == '__main__':
    commandline.main(sys.argv)
```

The README doesn't mention any other configurations that need to be done and says that it should be compatible with Python 3.3+ (I'm on Python 3.9.6).

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you runing this from cmd.exe?
If so try:

```
python.exe mut.py --target calculator --unit-test test_calculator -m
```

Note that you need python in your PATH Variable.

It will probably also work if you set python as the default application for .py files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. While I have gotten MutPy to run, it's reporting some errors. I'll see if going to a lower version of Python will resolve the issue (but needing to do so might be a dealbreaker for us). It seems that MutPy is a bit outdated, so I'm also considering looking at other mutation testing tools if possible. I was originally looking at mutmut, but it tends to stop running after a while due to some threading issues.

Comment: Also, I had to add the path to `mut.py` in the command: `python.exe C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\mut.py --target calculator --unit-test test_calculator -m`